# Checklistbox Multiple Selection

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I have been working on a application that uses a Checkedlistbox so I can allow the user to select multiple boxes.

```
    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    For Each item As Object In Me.CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        Dim text As String = Me.CheckedListBox1.GetItemText(item)
    Next

    If text = "Line 1" Then
        CreateLine1()
    End If

    If text = "Line 2" Then
        CreateLine2()
    End If

    If text = "Line 3" Then
        CreateLine3()
    End If

    If Text = "Line 4" Then
        CreateLine4()
    End If

    If Text = "Line 5" Then
        CreateLine5()
    End If
```

It goes all the way to "Line 10". When the app runs it use cmd.exe to connect to telnet and send commands. If I have Line 1 and Line 2 selected Line 1 has no problems, but when Line 2 run it opens a cmd does, nothing for a few seconds, open another cmd, and run just the commands while not connected to the telnet. Several more widows open afterwords and the four or fifth window connected to telnet.

How can I make it so if one line if selected after it has run telnet it separates out that line as "Has been ran" before going to the next line to avoid my problem.

***Addition info:***
This app has a select-all and deselect-all buttons so I can not have anything that will interfere with them.

I have try using socket to replace cmd.exe.....it did not go so well and I will pass on it.

Each sub the lines go to it basically the same except to the IP address and a few commands.

Comment: are you using the code above ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the original code you posted isn't actually what you're using...it doesn't seem quite right.

Perhaps something like this might be more useful:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Public Class Form1

    Private Methods As New List(Of MethodInfo)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim MI As MethodInfo
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            mi = Me.GetType.GetMethod("CreateLine" & i, Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
            If Not IsNothing(MI) Then
                Methods.Add(MI)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        For Each Index As Integer In Me.CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices
            Methods(Index).Invoke(Me, Nothing)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateLine1()
        Debug.Print("CreateLine1()")
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateLine2()
        Debug.Print("CreateLine2()")
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateLine3()
        Debug.Print("CreateLine3()")
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateLine4()
        Debug.Print("CreateLine4()")
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateLine5()
        Debug.Print("CreateLine5()")
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateLine6()
        Debug.Print("CreateLine6()")
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateLine7()
        Debug.Print("CreateLine7()")
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateLine8()
        Debug.Print("CreateLine8()")
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateLine9()
        Debug.Print("CreateLine9()")
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateLine10()
        Debug.Print("CreateLine10()")
    End Sub

End Class
```

There are lots of other ways to do this as well...

Comment: Great example and use of System.Reflection +1 !

Comment: The code works I just had to and a System.Threading.Thread.sleep() to the end of each sub before returning.

Comment: Can you edit your code in the original question to show how you are really calling this stuff and also show an example CreateLineX()?  There might be a better way than using Sleep()...